# Trying to get property of non-object works on one part of page but not on other

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm retrieving a row from my MySQL database using a prepared statement that works fine (tested in phpmyadmin) with the specific values etc.

I use `<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($row_feed->f_text)); ?>` to display it on line 400 of my page and again on line 900 (it's an actual copy paste). The first instance displays the result as expected and the second throws an error:

```
Uncaught Customizable_Exception: Trying to get property 'f_text' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\bbto.eu\index.php:878
```

How is that even possible? I've checked, the `$row_feed` variable is not reused for something else in between and it works fine in the same file a couple of lines ahead. The only thing is that the first instance is within this loop `while($row_feed = $feed->fetch_object()) {  }` while the other one is after it closes but since when has that any impact?

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM feed";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if(!$statement->execute()) { die("Query error: ".$statement->error); } 
$feed = $statement->get_result();

while ($row_feed = $feed->fetch_object()) {
echo (htmlspecialchars($row_feed->f_text));
}
### other stuff going on
echo (htmlspecialchars($row_feed->f_text));
```

I get my error on the second echo.

Comment: The basic principle of doing such a while loop over the query result, is that the `fetch` call will return NULL when there are no more records to be processed, and that is what makes the loop terminate at this point then. So of course _after_ your loop, $row_feed is NULL.

Comment: Please show us the [mcve]

Comment: After the `while` loop the value of `$row_feed` will be obviously null

Comment: @CBroe thanks for that - how can I reuse $row_feed's last value without making a new MySQL call then? I've tried data_seek(0) but that doesnt work since as you said, it's NULL...

Comment: It would be so much easier if you were using PDO. Why don't you switch to PDO? If you want to do this with mysqli then you need save the value in a separate variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing is that the first instance is within this loop while($row_feed = $feed->fetch_object()) {  } while the other one is after it closes but since when has that any impact?

The basic principle of doing such a while loop over the query result, is that the `fetch` call will return NULL when there are no more records to be processed, and that is what makes the loop terminate at this point then. So of course after your loop, `$row_feed` is NULL.

> how can I reuse $row_feed's last value

Store it into a different variable, *inside* the while loop: `$last_row = $row_feed;`. This will be overwritten in each loop iteration, so only the last value will “survive” after the loop. Since it is *inside* the loop, this line will not execute any more when `$row_feed = $feed->fetch_object()` has resulted in NULL.

```
while ($row_feed = $feed->fetch_object()) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($row_feed->f_text);
  $last_row = $row_feed;
}
### other stuff going on
echo htmlspecialchars($last_row);
```

Comment: (`echo htmlspecialchars(…);` makes rather little sense here, since these variables contain objects; but I followed the pseudocode example from the question here. Should be replaced with whatever is appropriate to output the content in the desired form.)